# Conjugate symmetry of an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, proof-writing, inner-products

I want to prove the following:

$\langle A,B \rangle = \overline{\langle B,A \rangle}$

where

$\langle A,B \rangle := tr(AB^{*})\,\, and \,\, A,B \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} $

Note:

The bar denotes the complex conjugate of all entries of a matrix and the "*" the adjoint matrix.

Edit:

$\langle A,B \rangle = tr(AB^{*}) = tr(\overline{(BA^{*})^T}) = tr(\overline{BA^{*}}) = \overline{tr(BA^*)} = \overline{\langle B,A \rangle}$

The third equality holds since A and B are square matrices.

Comment: Write down an explicit formula for $\langle A,B\rangle $ in terms of $A_{ij}, B_{ij}$, the entries of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I did it like this: $\langle A,B \rangle = tr(AB^*) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} (AB^*)_{jj}$

Comment: There is not need to use the elements of the matrices. Did you see my answer?

Comment: Yes I did but for me personally it didn't really help me. I did prove it now, I will add an edit to my original answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just observe that $(AB^*)^*=B^{**}A^*=BA^*$ and therefore the matrices $AB^*$ and $BA^*$ are complex conjugate of each other. Their diagonal elements are thus conjugate and their sums are as well, that is, $tr(AB^*)=\overline{tr(BA^*)}$